# What is the difference between DbType and Type in SqlParameter?

Tags: asp.net, sqldatasource

Can you explain me the difference between Type and DbType in a parameter of a datasource?
What is the best pratice of assigning these two properties?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type Represents type declarations: class types, interface types, array types, value types, enumeration types, type parameters, generic type definitions, and open or closed constructed generic types.

like `Int32, String`, complex types

it is for front-end referene

ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx

While
DBType
Specifies SQL Server-specific data type of a field, property, for use in a SqlParameter.

ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype.asp

So this means: you must use `Type` when referencing from DB to C#/VB

and `DBType` when referencing/Passing values to DB From C#/VB

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 2):

The answer does not hold good always. For some cases setting DBType of the procedure parameter from VB .Net fails for no reason (even if [param].DBType is set to sqlDBType.Decimal, the [param].sqlDBType got set to DateTime, resulting in an invalid cast error while invoking the procedure with valid decimal values for the parameter). Solution was that I had to set [param].sqlDBType specifically instead of setting the DBType property. Still not clear what all this really implies.

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.dbtype(v=vs.110).aspx) :

> The SqlDbType and DbType are linked. Therefore, setting 
>       the DbType changes the SqlDbType to a supporting SqlDbType.